# Subgroups of order $p$ and $p^{n-1}$ in a group of order $p^n$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, p-groups

I have a group $G$ of order $p^n$ for $n \ge 1$ and $p$ a prime.  I am looking for two specific subgroups within $G$: one of order $p$ and one of order $p^{n-1}$. I don't think I would use the Sylow theorems here because those seem to apply to groups with a "messier" order than simply $p^n$. Would Cauchy's Theorem allow me to generate the two requisite subgroups? I could use it to find an element of order $p$ and an element of order $p^{n-1}$ and then consider the cyclic subgroups generated by these two elements?

Comment: Your idea is good for the subgroup of order $p$.  But you can't use Cauchy's theorem to get an element of order $p^{n-1}$ (and no such element will exist in many cases).

Comment: Then letting $a \in G$ be an element of order $p$, perhaps I should consider $G/\langle a \rangle$?

Comment: @JJR $\langle a\rangle$ need not be normal for arbitrary $a$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hints:

1) Use the [class formula](http://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=6&ved=0CFAQFjAF&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpeople.brandeis.edu%2F~igusa%2FMath101aF07%2FMath101a_notesA45.pdf&ei=nBMhUZXhPMXLtAaYg4HICA&usg=AFQjCNFSXo2y60Jnll1mcT5moNnuW1GgEw&sig2=u7pDJbpadaVHWirV7-3WfQ) and deduce that $\,|Z(G)|>1\,$

2) Use induction now to show that $\,G\,$ has *a normal subgroup* of order $\,p^k\,\,,\,\,\forall\,\,0\le k\le n\,$

Comment: Looks tractable. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 7):

> Let $P$ act on itself by conjugation. $1$ appears in an orbit of size $1$, and everything else appears in an orbit of size $p^k$ for some $k$.  Since the sum of the orbit sizes is equal to $|P|$, which is congruent to $0\mod{p}$, that means there has to be at least one more orbit of size $1$.  Orbits of size $1$ under conjugation contain elements which commute with everything in the group; they compose $Z(P)$.  Now suppose inductively that $\exists S\unlhd P$ with $|S|=p^k$.  Then by the above lemma and Cauchy's theorem $P/S$ has a central subgroup $\overline{Q}$ of order $p$.  Lifting $\overline{Q}$ back to $P$, we obtain a normal subgroup of order $p^{k+1}$.