# Group of order $40$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I need to show that any group $G$ such that $|G|=40$ has 3 subgroups $H_1,H_2,H_3$ such that $H_1<H_2<H_3$ and their orders are $5,10,20$ accordingly.

Thanks a million!

Comment: Do you have any thoughts on the matter? Do you know Cauchy's theorem or Sylow's theorems? Could you find a subgroup of order $5$, to start with?

Comment: Yes, I have found that the group $G$ must have exactly one 5-sylow subgroup, and as such this subgroup is also normal. I also know that there is an element of order $2$ in $G$, and thus I could construct $H_2$, my biggest difficulty is with constructing $H_3$. Thanks!

Comment: To find $H_3$ you can find a subgroup of $G/H_1$ of index two and look at its preimage in $G$

Comment: I can't see how to find a subgroup of $G/H_1$ of index two unfortunately.

Comment: @giladYehudai This is a property of $p$-groups: you can find subgroups of every possible order

Comment: I'm not aware of this property. Is there any other way to find such a group, or go about this problem?

Comment: You can prove @Cocopuffs claim by induction on the order of a $p$-group using the fact that every $p$-group has non-trivial centre. In turn, you can prove that every $p$-group has non-trivial centre using the class equation.

Answer (score 2):

You know that the group has a unique (and thus normal) $5$-Sylow subgroup, so call this $H_1$.

You also know that the group has at least one $2$-Sylow subgroup, which will have order $8$. Now, this also means that the group will have subgroups of order $2$ and $4$ (see for example [A group of order $8$ has a subgroup of order $4$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/441241/a-group-of-order-8-has-a-subgroup-of-order-4/)).

Let $A$ be a subgroup of order $2$ and $B$ be a subgroup of order $4$ with $A\leq B$. Now since $H_1$ is normal, both $H_2 = H_1A$ and $H_3 = H_1B$ are subgroups, and it is easy to check that they satisfy the requirements.